# How to set access_type=offline using spring boot security and oauth flow to generate a refresh tokenn

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Sprint boot security + OAuth2 with google to integrate the with google. I have registered google as a oauth2 client in InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository using following propperties.

```
private ClientRegistration googleClientRegistration() {
       Map<String ,Object> configMap = new HashMap<>();
       configMap.put("access_type","offline");
       return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("g_mail")
               .clientId(googleClientId)
               .clientSecret(googleSecret)
               .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
               .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
               .redirectUri(redirectURI.replace("source", "G_MAIL"))
               .scope("openid","email","profile","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly")
               .authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")
               .tokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
               .providerConfigurationMetadata(configMap)
               .userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
               .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
               .jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")
               .clientName("Google").build();
   }
```

After user has successfully authorised and authenticated, we are receiving the authorization code in the call back handler. When using this authorization code to generate a access token, I am unable to get refresh token. Could you please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Note:- I have configured these client registration repository as a bean. As we will be using these access tokens to access user's data. Let me know if you need more inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have solved by my self. Following is my solution. I have update the authorization api and it worked

authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&prompt=consent")

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and found another solution using spring boot configurations, inspired by your solution:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            clientId: YOUR_CLIENT_ID
            clientSecret: YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
            scope:
              - email
              - profile
        provider:
          google:
            authorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&prompt=consent
```

Edit:
Just found an old answer on github: [how to set access_type=offline to get the refresh token from google.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7003)